# Modbus 2.0 handling exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api2, modbus

I am working on `web-api` in which I a using a `Modbus` protocol library by [sontx](https://bitbucket.org/sontx/dotnet-utils/src/master/Code4Bugs.Utils/IO/Modbus/). In the documentation, it is mentioned.

**Exception handling**

There are several cases that the response is corrupted, nothing response (maybe the slave is down),... In these cases, an exception will be thrown, a `try-catch` statement should be used to handle in these cases.

There are three kinds of exception: - `EmptyResponsedException`: The slave does not respond anything, that seems like the slave is down, the connection is broken... - `MissingDataException`: The response bytes is less than the required, ex: the length of the required bytes is 11 but the length of the received bytes is 9. - `DataCorruptedException`: Checksum is failed, wrong response slave id, wrong response function code...

```
try {
var responseBytes = stream.RequestFunc3(0x11, 0x006B, 0x0003);
// handle your response bytes
}
catch(Exception e) {
if (e is DataCorruptedException) {
    BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent("checksum is failed", e);
}
else if (e is EmptyResponsedException) {
    BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent("request timeout", e);
}
else if (e is MissingDataException) {
    BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent("Missing response bytes", e);
}
else {
    throw e;
}
}
```

When I am trying to add this piece of code into my code I am getting bellow error

> The name 'BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent' does not exist in the current context

[image]

I am trying to find it's a solution but I got nothing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent` is just an arbitraty method in the example. You have to implement your own error handling depending on the exception type.

Comment: Can you please provide me any sample?

Answer (score 0):

"BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent" is just an example method name that the documentation uses to demonstrate how you might handle catching the exception types. You can replace it with your own method to output the exception message to the UI, write it to a log, etc..

E.g. using their same method name (with functionality to "broadcast" the exception if necessary):

```
class ModbusTest
{
    public event EventHandler<string> ModbusExceptionThrown;

    public void TestRead()
    {
        try
        {
            var responseBytes = stream.RequestFunc3(0x11, 0x006B, 0x0003);
            // handle your response bytes
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e is DataCorruptedException)
            {
                BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent("checksum is failed", e);
            }
            else if (e is EmptyResponsedException)
            {
                BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent("request timeout", e);
            }
            else if (e is MissingDataException)
            {
                BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent("Missing response bytes", e);
            }
            else
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    // logs exception stacktrace to console and raises event with message string
    protected virtual void BroadcastHandledExceptionEvent(string Message, Exception Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.StackTrace);
        EventHandler<string> handler = ModbusExceptionThrown;
        handler?.Invoke(this, Message);
    }
}
```

Now your parent object can listen for the modbus exception message, or if that's not necessary you can simply log them to the console, to a file, or whatever.